# Ternary operation with a "negative" variable

Tags: java, ternary, negative-integer

What does the negative variable do in a ternary? Why is the output `-10 is 10`?

```
public class Ternary {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i, k;
        i = -10;
        k = i < 0 ? -i : i;
        System.out.print(i + " is " + k);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain the function of the variable in this scenario? What does `-i` mean?

Comment: I have never heard of a negative variable before.  What is it?  Do you mean "a variable that has a negative numeric value"?

Comment: Yes it is.the variable 'i' is changed to '-i' in ternary operation.

Comment: A better term would possibly be to *negate* the variable or as you're using it -- to get the variable's *absolute value*.

Comment: Read the Fine Manual http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html "Unary Operators" Also in the following subject the discussion of the conditional​ operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [unary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) `-(-(1))` is `1`. It's a longer way to write

```
int i = -10, k = Math.abs(i);
```

Comment: What is the internal operation happens in this scenario? how 'i' is changed to '-i'?

Comment: You are saying `k = -i` if `i < 0`. That is how `i` is changed into `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

It first checks

-10 < 0, which turns out to be true.

Thus, 'k' will be assigned with value -(-10) as i = -10. The result becomes 10.

Then you have the answer

-10 is 10 as value of i remains unchanged